# Get the sum of a column and put the value in a TextView

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I am making an application but I'm stuck. I'm unsure on how to get the sum of a column and put the value into a `TextView`. I also want to delete an item when a list item is long pressed. I know how to work with a long press but I just don't know how to get that list item name or id when an item is longed pressed. Here is my `DbOperation.java` class:

```
package com.wavedevelopers.databaseasynctaskdemo;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Haider885 on 25/08/2016.
 */
public class DbOperation extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "ProductInfo1.db";
    private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME +
            "( "+ ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID + " TEXT, " + ProductContract.ProductEntry.NAME + " TEXT, " +
            ProductContract.ProductEntry.PRICE + " FLOAT, " + ProductContract.ProductEntry.QTY + " FLOAT, "+ ProductContract.ProductEntry.TOTAL + " FLOAT );";



    public DbOperation(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        Log.d("Database Opeation","Database Created...");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database Opeation","Table Created...");

    }

    public void addProduct(SQLiteDatabase DB, String id, String name, float price, float qty,float total)
    {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID,id);
        contentValues.put(ProductContract.ProductEntry.NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(ProductContract.ProductEntry.PRICE,price);
        contentValues.put(ProductContract.ProductEntry.QTY,qty);
        contentValues.put(ProductContract.ProductEntry.TOTAL,total);

        DB.insert(ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        Log.d("Database Opeation","One Row Inserted...");


    }

    public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String[] projections = {ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID, ProductContract.ProductEntry.NAME, ProductContract.ProductEntry.PRICE, ProductContract.ProductEntry.QTY, ProductContract.ProductEntry.TOTAL};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME,projections,null,null,null,null,null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public String getGrandTotal(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String total = null;

        String[] projections = {ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID, ProductContract.ProductEntry.NAME, ProductContract.ProductEntry.PRICE, ProductContract.ProductEntry.QTY, ProductContract.ProductEntry.TOTAL};
        db.execSQL("SELECT SUM("+ ProductContract.ProductEntry.TOTAL +") FROM " + ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME + ";");
        db.close();
        return total;
    }

    public void deleteContact(Product product) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(ProductContract.ProductEntry.TABLE_NAME, ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(product.getId()) });
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Here is my `BackgroundTask.java` class:

```
package com.wavedevelopers.databaseasynctaskdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Haider885 on 25/08/2016.
 */
public class BackgrounTask extends AsyncTask<String,Product,String> {

    Context ctx;

    ProductAdapter productAdapter;

    Activity activity;
    ListView listView;

    BackgrounTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        activity = (Activity) ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String method = params[0];
        DbOperation dbOperation = new DbOperation(ctx);
        if (method.equals("add_info"))
        {
            String id = params[1];
            String name = params[2];
            float price = Float.parseFloat(params[3]);
            float qty = Float.parseFloat(params[4]);
            float total = Float.parseFloat(params[5]);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbOperation.getWritableDatabase();
            dbOperation.addProduct(db,id,name,price,qty,total);

            return "Saved...";


        }

        else if (method.equals("get_info"))
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbOperation.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = dbOperation.getInformation(db);

            productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(ctx,R.layout.display_product_row);

            listView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.display_listview);

            String id,name;
            float price,qty,total;

            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.ID));
                name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.NAME));
                price = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.PRICE));
                qty = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.QTY));
                total = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProductContract.ProductEntry.TOTAL));

                Product product = new Product(id,name,price,qty,total);
                publishProgress(product);
            }

            return "get_info";


        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Product... values) {
        productAdapter.add(values[0]);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("get_info"))
        {
            listView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Those are 3 or 4 different questions (how to sum columns, how to write something to a text view, how to detect a long press on a listview, how to delete an item in a list).  Break this up into parts.

Comment: I know how to detect long press and write something in textview

Comment: What do you mean by the total of each column? Do you mean the total number of values in each column?

Comment: For example I have 3 columns in data base Id, Product and Price. Price have some FLOAT Values. So what will be total of Price column. I got the query to sum the column. "SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;" . But don't know how to get the value.